# How do I assign setInterval to variable and clear it in React + Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

That what I came at best so far:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ItemList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            percent: 0
        }
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                percent: this.state.percent + 1
            })
        }, 50)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.percent >= this.props.number) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            console.log(2)
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <li className="skills__programmer__content__item">
                <div className="skills__programmer__content__item__name">{this.props.title}</div>
                <div className="skills__programmer__content__item__percent">{ this.state.percent + "%"} </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

ItemList.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    number: PropTypes.number,
}

export default ItemList;
```

I just want a component which increments val up to certain number.
My logic was in componentDidMount start setInterval and in componenDidUpdated check if value is greater or equal desired then stop interval. That what I did but having issue with storing setInterval. It gives me error "this.interval is not a function". I'm crying

Comment: I have answered your query. Also the code you shared isn't **hooks** code but the **Class** lifecycle one. I don't understand the context for **Hooks** in your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the below sample code which closely resembles yours and does what you want to do :-

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percent: 0
    };
    this.intervalId = null;
  }

  startInterval() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        percent: this.state.percent + 1
      });
    }, 50);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startInterval();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.percent >= this.props.number) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="skills__programmer__content__item">
        {this.state.percent}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  number: PropTypes.number
};

export default App;
```

The key point is that `setInterval(..)` returns a **unique id** which is used later to clear it using `clearInterval`. So this resolves your `this.interval()` error because `this.interval` is a `number` and not a `function`.

Now coming to starting the interval, you can wrap your `setInterval` logic inside a `startInterval` function which you call inside `componentDidMount()` and keep track of the **unique interval id** by using `this.intervalId` which you will use to clear the interval once your `if` condition in `componentDidUpdate()` gets satisfied.

**Note - your current code can work simply by removing `this.interval()` also but that means that your interval starts in the constructor itself. I think `componentDidMount()` should be the place for it as you intended.**

Here is a working sandbox :-

[image: Edit Class lifecycle timer - StackOverflow]

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `this.interval is not a function` because you are calling this.interval into componentDidMount, but that isn't necessary. The interval is already defined in the constructor and it starts in that moment.
To fix it, just remove componentDidMount